# what is the meaning of "under his own initials" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

what is the meaning of "under his own initials" in this context?

> Mrs. Fox and her three daughters began public sittings in New York in
>   the spring of 1850, at Barnum's Hotel, and they attracted many curious
>   visitors. The Press was almost unanimous in denunciation of them. A
>   brilliant exception to this was found in Horace Greeley, already
>   quoted, who wrote an appreciative article in his paper **under his own
>   initials**. A portion of this will be found in the Appendix.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 3):

It means he didn't write a newspaper article anonymously. If you search "Greeley" in the link you provided, you find the article he wrote, followed by the initials "H.G.".